# How to dynamically change text by HTML tag in a Shiny app?

Tags: html, shiny

I would like to be able to dynamically change the label on a numericInput widget and also html tag. I know how to do this for the numericInput widget by using uiOutput and renderUI. I am not sure however how to achieve the same for a text printed by the h4 tag.

The reprex is below:

```r
library(shiny)

ui=(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("vvv"),
    radioButtons("rb", "Choose conversion", choices = c("A to B"="1", "B to A"="2"),selected = "1"),
    h4("Value B or A (dependant on radio button selection):"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text")
  )
))

server = (function(input, output) {

  output$vvv <- renderUI({
    if (input$rb == 1) {
    numericInput("vvv", "Enter A", value = 1)
    } else {
      numericInput("vvv", "Enter B", value = 2) 
    }
  })


  output$text <- renderPrint(input$vvv*2)


})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

When the “A to B” radio button is selected the text above the verbatumTextOutput should read “Value of B” and when the “B to A” is selected to read “Value of A”.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `renderUI` again. The UI being the HTML. Or you could use `conditionalPanel`. Or a more direct JavaScript solution with the `shinyjs` package.

Comment: @teofil Thank you! I have looked at using the conditionalPanel approach and it works  really well. I think using the HTMLin renderUI is also interesting but couldn't figure it out as my HTML knowledge is very limited.